# Не создается второй узел для односвязного списка(C++)

Tags: c++, классы, односвязный-список

Имеется два класса:
CNode - для узла списка.
CNode.h:

```
#pragma once

class CNode
{
    char* Type, * Mark;
    float Power;
    CNode* Next;
public:
    CNode();
    ~CNode();
    void setNext(CNode* nextnode);
    CNode* getNext();

    void setType(char* newType);
    char* getType();

    void setMark(char* newMark);
    char* getMark();

    void setPower(float newPower);
    float getPower();
    void operator = (const CNode & op);

    void setAllNode(char* newType, char* newMark, float newPower);
};
```

CNode.cpp

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "CNode.h"

CNode::CNode() : Type(0), Mark(0), Power(0), Next(0)
{ }
CNode::~CNode()
{ 
    if (Type) delete Type;
    if (Mark) delete Mark;
}

void CNode::setNext(CNode* nextnode)
{
    Next = nextnode;
}

CNode* CNode::getNext()
{
    return Next;
}
//--Type--
void CNode::setType(char* newType)
{
    if (this->Type) delete this->Type;
    int len = strlen(newType) + 1;
    this->Type = new char[len];
    strcpy_s(this->Type, len, newType);
}
char* CNode::getType()
{
    return Type;
}
//--Mark--
void CNode::setMark(char* newMark)
{
    if (this->Mark) delete this->Mark;
    int len = strlen(newMark) + 1;
    this->Mark = new char[len];
    strcpy_s(this->Mark, len, newMark);
}
char* CNode::getMark()
{
    return Mark;
}
//--Power--
void CNode::setPower(float newPower)
{
    Power = newPower;
}
float CNode::getPower()
{
    return Power;
}

void CNode::setAllNode(char* newType, char* newMark, float newPower)
{
    setType(newType);
    setMark(newMark);
    setPower(newPower);
}

void CNode::operator = (const CNode & op)
{
    setType(op.Type);
    setMark(op.Mark);
    setPower(op.Power);
    setNext(op.Next);//Правка
}
```

CListOf - для списка.

CListOf.h

```
#pragma once
#include "CNode.h"

class CListOf
{
    CNode* First, * Current;
    int NodeCount;
    CNode* GetLastNode();
public:
    CListOf();
    ~CListOf();
    void AddNode(const CNode& node);
    CNode* GetCurrentNode();
    bool MoveToNextNode();
    bool MoveToFirstNode();
    int GetNodeCount();
};
```

CListOf.cpp

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "CListOf.h"

CListOf::CListOf()
{
    First = Current = NULL;
    NodeCount = 0;
}
CListOf::~CListOf()
{
    Current = First;
    while (Current)
    {
        Current = First->getNext();
        delete First;
        First = Current;
    }
}

void CListOf::AddNode(const CNode& node)
{
    if (!First) Current = First = new CNode;
    else
    {
        Current = GetLastNode(); //Правка
        Current -> CNode::setNext(new CNode);
        Current = Current -> getNext();
    }
    *Current = node;
    ++NodeCount;
}

CNode* CListOf::GetCurrentNode()
{
    return Current;
}

bool CListOf::MoveToNextNode()
{
    if (Current -> getNext())
    { 
        Current = Current -> getNext();
        return true;
    }
    Current = NULL;
    return false;
}

bool CListOf::MoveToFirstNode()
{
    if (First) { Current = First; return true; }
    else { Current = NULL; return false; }
}

CNode * CListOf::GetLastNode()
{
    if (!First) return NULL;
    if (!(Current -> getNext())) return Current;
    CNode* Temp = First;
    for (int i = 0; i < NodeCount - 1; i++) Temp = Temp -> getNext();
    return Temp;
}

int CListOf::GetNodeCount()
{
    return NodeCount;
}
```

В процессе выполнения программы создается и выводится только один узел, но возникает ошибка при создании второго.
Вот код самой программы:

```
void main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    CListOf list;
    CNode node;
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("engines.txt");
    if (!fin.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Не удалось прочитать файл" << endl;
        return;
    }
    char type[123], mark[123];
    float power;
    while (1)
    {
        if (fin.eof() != true)
        {
            fin >> type >> mark >> power;

            node.setAllNode(type, mark, power);
            list.AddNode(node);  //Тут возникает ошибка
            printList(list);
        }

        if (!(list.MoveToNextNode())) break;
    }
}
```

На второй итерации цикла while, после записи и выведения первого узла, вызывается исключение в `list.AddNode(node)` в строчке с `CNode::setNext(new CNode)`, . Ее реализация описана в CListOf.cpp:

```
void CListOf::AddNode(const CNode& node)
{
    if (!First) Current = First = new CNode;
    else
    {
        Current -> CNode::setNext(new CNode);
        Current = Current -> getNext();
    }
    *Current = node;
    ++NodeCount;
}
```

Реализация `CNode::setNext(CNode* nextnode)`:

```
void CNode::setNext(CNode* nextnode)
{
    Next = nextnode; //Конкретно тут вызывается исключение
}
```

Текст исключения:
Вызвано исключение: нарушение доступа для чтения.
this было 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE7.

Прошу помочь с причиной возникновения этой ошибки.

Правки: добавлены пара строк помеченные `//Правка`
Но это не помогло:)
Результат выполнения тот же, а исключение вызывается в `getNext()` из строки с `if (!(Current -> getNext())) return Current;` :

```
CNode * CListOf::GetLastNode()
{
    if (!First) return NULL;
    if (!(Current -> getNext())) return Current; //Тут
    CNode* Temp = First;
    for (int i = 0; i < NodeCount - 1; i++) Temp = Temp -> getNext();
    return Temp;
}
```

А переход в`CNode * CListOf::GetLastNode()` происходит из `list.AddNode(node);` на второй итерации цикла `while`:

```
CNode* CNode::getNext()
{
    return Next; //нарушение доступа для чтения.
                 //this было 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE7.
}
```

Comment: Перепишите все это попроще. Меньше классов и конструкторов. Просто структуры и ручная установка всех указателей (без вспомогательных методов). Ошибка сразу станет понятной. (просто лень лазить вперед-назад по всей этой простыне)

Comment: По крайней мере после этого `*Current = node;` в `AddNode()` надо  добавить`Current->Next = 0;`

Answer (score 0):

Когда-то давно делал похожую реализацию для ардуинки. Фактический реализация та-же самая что у тебя.

- https://github.com/latdev/eugenetaskstool

Вообще если ты используешь плюсы, лучше используй std::list

Answer (score 0):

Заменил `strcpy_s` на `strcpy`, первый элемент добавляется. Но до второй итерации цикл не доходит.

```
bool CListOf::MoveToNextNode()
{
    if (Current->getNext()) // Current указывает на первый элемент списка, Current->getNext() == NULL
    { 
        Current = Current->getNext();
        return true;
    }
    Current = NULL; // Обнуляем Current ??? Раньше он указывал на 1 элемент, теперь - в никуда
    return false; // возвращаем 0
}

 while (1)
    {
       ...
       if (!(list.MoveToNextNode()))  // и выходим из цикла
          break;
    }
```

Comment: Но я вроде нигде не использовал `strlen_s`

Comment: Извините - описка. `strcpy_s` на `strcpy`. Исправил.